# JavaFx: How to set the labelFor property of a Label in FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a TextField and a Label with mnemonicParsing true.  I want to set the labelFor property of the label with the id of the TextField. How do I do that in FXML?

```
<GridPane hgap="5.0" snapToPixel="false" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
      <Label maxWidth="-Infinity" text="_A Label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER" mnemonicParsing="true" />
      <TextField id="myTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" />
</children>
</GridPane>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the dollar notation:

```
<GridPane hgap="5.0" snapToPixel="false" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
          <Label labelFor="$myTextField" maxWidth="-Infinity" text="_A Label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER" mnemonicParsing="true"  />
          <TextField id="myTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: I think `id="myTextField"` should be `fx:id="myTextField"` here

Comment: I found that for me this only works if the referenced node (TextField) is declared *before* the label that references it in the FXML file.

Answer (score 4):

If found the solution...

```
<GridPane hgap="5.0" snapToPixel="false" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
      <Label maxWidth="-Infinity" text="_A Label" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" GridPane.vgrow="NEVER" mnemonicParsing="true">
           <labelFor>
               <TextField id="myTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="NEVER" />
           </labelFor>
      </Label>
      <fx:reference source="myTextField" />
</children>
</GridPane>
```